# Empty Dynamic List

Tags: c++

I've created a simple dynamic template list and i'm having some issue clearing the entire list.

**List.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <Node.h>

template <class T> class List
{
public:
    typedef Node<T> node_type;
    typedef node_type* node_pointer;
    typedef T data_type;
    typedef T& reference_type;

    List();
    void push_back(data_type);
    reference_type at(int);
    void clear();
    void swap(int,int);
    int size();

private:
    int list_size = 0;
    node_pointer head, tail;
};

template <class T> List<T>::List()
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
}

template <class T> void List<T>::push_back(data_type data)
{
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new node_type(data);
        tail = head;
    } else {
        node_pointer temp = new node_type(data);
        temp->setNextNull();
        tail->setNext(temp);
        tail = tail->getNext();
    }
    list_size++;
}

template <class T> typename List<T>::reference_type List<T>::at(int x)
{
    node_pointer pointer=head;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
        pointer=pointer->getNext();

    return pointer->getData();
}

template <class T> void List<T>::clear()
{
    node_pointer pointer = head;
    for(int i=0; i<list_size; i++) {
        node_pointer temp = pointer;
        pointer=pointer->getNext();
        delete(temp);
    }
    head=NULL;
    list_size=0;
}



template <class T> void List<T>::swap(int x, int y)
{
    data_type buffer=at(x);
    at(x)=at(y);
    at(y)=buffer;
}

template <class T> int List<T>::size()
{
    return list_size;
}

#endif // LIST_H
```

**Node.h**

```
template <class T> class Node
{
public:
    typedef T data_type;
    typedef T& reference_type;

    Node(data_type _data);
    void setData(data_type);
    void setNextNull();
    void setNext(Node*);

    reference_type getData();
    Node* getNext();

private:
    data_type data;
    Node* next;
};


template <class T> Node<T>::Node(data_type _data) : data(_data)
{
    setNextNull();
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setData(data_type _data)
{
    data=_data;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setNextNull()
{
    next=NULL;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setNext(Node* _next)
{
    next=_next;
}

template <class T> typename Node<T>::reference_type Node<T>::getData()
{
    return data;
}

template <class T> typename Node<T>::Node* Node<T>::getNext()
{
    return next;
}
```

If I clear the list calling the "clear" method I get all sorts of errors in almost every other method, but if I use the version below the list works perfectly.

```
template <class T> void List<T>::clear()
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    list_size=0;
}
```

The problem only appears if I use the delete function to clear memory. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: "If I clear the list calling the "clear" method I get all sorts of errors". What errors?

Comment: You'll get a solution faster if you post a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: you don't set the `tail` in your `clear`.

Comment: I'd rather say she/he redundantly sets `tail` to null in the ctor. ;) Seriously, the only issue that can cause errors in the code is that the list type itself is copyable and assignable, with the typical implications when types contain pointers that represent exclusive ownership. There's another thing I would do to make things a bit smaller and easier to understand and that is to put everything into a single file without out-of-line definitions. I would then make the node class a nested class, private inside the list class, and make it a simple struct without any memberfunctions.

Comment: I get Segmentation fault only if I call delete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very dangerious, because you skipped important checks. Try to use following implementation of `at()`:

```
template <class T> typename List<T>::reference_type List<T>::at(int x)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= list_size || list_size <= 0)
        return DATA_WITH_ERROR_FLAG; // since you return data instead of pointer,
                                     // you can't return NULL here
                                     // (you need special constant for error status
                                     //  or support it another way)

    node_pointer pointer=head;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        if (!pointer)
            return DATA_WITH_ERROR_FLAG;
        pointer=pointer->getNext();
    }

    if (!pointer)
        return DATA_WITH_ERROR_FLAG;
    return pointer->getData();
}
```

After it you have to add checks after each `at()` call. For example, you have to modify `swap()` to make it safe too:

```
template <class T> void List<T>::swap(int x, int y)
{
    data_type v1=at(x);
    data_type v2=at(y);
    if (v1 == DATA_WITH_ERROR_FLAG || v2 == DATA_WITH_ERROR_FLAG)
        return; // and somehow set error flag!
    data_type t=v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = t;
}
```

I.e. you need to check correctness everywhere if you don't like such problems. And it is necessary to support returninig of error status to simplify analysis of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak in your code. You don't delete all the list by simply pointing `head` and `tail` to `NULL`.

The best way to do this is to create a `delete()` function then loop through the whole list while it is not empty and delete node by node.

```
void deleteHead()
{
    if(head != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        size--;
    }
}
bool isEmpty()
{
    return head==NULL;
    //return size == 0; <-- this is ok as well.
}
void clear()
{
    while(! isEmpty())
    {
        deleteHead();
    }
    tail = head; //head = NULL
}
```

Comment: I get "Segmentation fault" if I delete every Node from my list, but not if I just set head and tail to NULL!

Comment: check your insert method .. or constructor

Comment: I don't understand... My constructor is almost empty!

Comment: your seg fault is caused because of your at(int x) function.
You don't check if `x < list_size` nor your check if `list_size > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `clear()` method to this:

```
template <class T> void List<T>::clear()
{
    node_pointer pointer = head;
    while (pointer != NULL) {
        node_pointer temp = pointer-getNext();
        delete pointer;
        pointer = temp;
    }
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    list_size=0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I still get Segmentation fault!

Comment: That means you are accessing invalid memory. Your node pointers are likely not pointing at valid node objects, which means you are not managing them correctly prior to calling `clear()`. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating how you are using `List`. Also, read about ["Rule of 3"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)) (and "Rule of 5" in C++)